# javascript jquery tofixed doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, tofixed

Why does this not work? Can anyone explain this to me?

```
t = setInterval(refresh_div,100);
    function refresh_div2() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:'livesatoshi.php',
        type:'POST',
        success:function(results2) {
            jQuery(".satoshi").html(results2).tofixed(2);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Maybe try `jQuery(".satoshi").html(results2.tofixed(2));` instead ?

Comment: did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

The function name is not correct and the toFixed function needs to be corrected , as below :-

```
t = setInterval(refresh_div2(),100);

success:function(results2){
    jQuery(".satoshi").html(results2.toFixed(2));
}
```

Put the above code in proper place and you will get your desired result .

Comment: results2 isn't likely to  be a number either.

Comment: Are you getting the expected results ?

Comment: I'm not the op, I'm just saying you'll likely have to convert result2 to a number before calling toFixed on it.

Comment: I don't know what type of data is being send back , hoping that the JQuery is catching a number .

Comment: nothing is working.
i try'd this , but it isnt working either : 

    function refresh_div() {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'livecredits.php',
            type:'POST',
            success:function(results) {
                jQuery(".credits.toFixed(2)").Number.parseFloat(results).toFixed(2);
            }
        });
    }

    t = setInterval(refresh_div,100);

Answer (score 0):

**[toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)** is case sensitive and is only a prototype function for Number data types.  results2 is likely not a Number type at this point, so you'll need to convert it to one with `Number.parseFloat()`.

Assuming you want the value of results2 as a number with 2 decimal points, you'll want to use:

```
Number.parseFloat(results2).toFixed(2); // returns "###.##" as a string
```

Comment: careful with this as parseFloat returns NaN if the result is empty or non-numeric.